# How to refresh a materialized view in mongoDB by passing a parameter into it

Tags: mongodb, view

I am working on creating a materialized view in mongoDB which is capable of refreshing itself, I am using mongoDB compass and inside that I am using the mongo shell to create the function which will create a materialized view. The MV should be able to refresh in 4 hours of interval and while refreshing it should update itself with any new row added to the table it is pointing to. I am using mongoDB compass only , I have seen many example where people are using mongoDB Atlas which is creating a cron which is firing the function to update the MV, but my limitation is I can not use the Atlas. So instead I have planned to create a MV and there should be some functionality to update it manually so that I can create java job which will call the MV at certain interval.

I have tried to create a MV which will take a date and from that date it will take the month, and will  refresh the MV for the dates which are greater than the date

```
updateSampleMVItems = 
  function(startDate){
  db.a-custom-db.aggregate([
  {$match:dates_of_valid_items:{$gte:"startDate"}}},
  {$group:{_id:{du_code:"$du_code",
  itg_name:"$itg_name",
  viewSample:"$viewSample",
  hoc:"$hoc"}}},
  {$merge:{into:"HourlyUpdateItems", whenMatched:"replace"}}
  ]);
  };
```

I can see the function is created , but when i am trying to call the function using

```
 updateSampleMVItems("2021-06-30")
```

I am getting error

```
ReferenceError: now is not defined
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:53:172
at updateSampleMVItems (evalmachine.<anonymous>:86:15)
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:44:156
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:58:7
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:63:5
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:64:3
at Script.runInContext (vm.js:134:20)
at Object.runInContext (vm.js:297:6)
```

I am not able to find the issue why it is not working

Comment: Try, `{$gte:startDate}`, without quotes.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i am still getting error , updated my question

Comment: Actually the error message "now is not defined" does not fit to your code. There is no "now" in your code. Please verify.